how to install/extend a custom rest extension in MarkLogic using ml-gradle?
I want to have ml-gradle to install/extend the custom rest endpoint, via ml-gradle.
Could you please provide some sample example or details, how to configure the ml-gradle for that?
I am able to create an HTTP app server and all using ml-gradle, but not sure how to extend the custom rest extension on that http port.
https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/extensions#id_41710
In above url, using curl command, we install it. But can we do it using ml-gradle?

See https://github.com/marklogic/ml-gradle/wiki/How-modules-are-loaded - specifically, just toss your REST extension into the services directory. Then run mlLoadModules or just mlDeploy.
